# Determinant of the matrix representation of an isomorphic linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, vector-space-isomorphism

Are there any theorems or special properties about the determinant of a matrix representation of an isomorphic linear transformation?

Comment: Yes: $A$ is an isomorphism if and only if $\det A \neq 0$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a linear transformation, being an isomorphism means exactly being invertible. A linear transformation is invertible if and only if any matrix corresponding to it is invertible.

A matrix is invertible if and only if its determinant is not zero.

Therefore, a linear transformation is an isomorphism if and only if any matrix corresponding to it has non-zero determinant.